# how to make an indicator shape view in RecycleView Items in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, layout

Hello I have a Recycle View items in my android application and I would like to do a shape view like the picture below, or someone can give a library that's allow me to somthing like this.?

[image: Picture]

Below is the layout of the item, I have done to create an item like the pic above but, I can't make the shape view in the left of the item, so I want of someone help me to do that, thank you

layout_item.xml

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/item_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/client_selector"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/num_bon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:text="000015"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textSize="13dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_bon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/num_bon"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="14/08/2017"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="@color/vert_clair"
                android:textSize="13dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nbr_p"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="15"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                android:layout_below="@+id/date_bon"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/num_bon"
                android:layout_marginTop="33dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/title_from_to_dots"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/nbr_p"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/date_bon"
                android:src="@drawable/from_to_purple" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nom_client"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/date_bon"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/title_from_to_dots"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/title_from_to_dots"
                android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
                android:text="John  smith"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="@color/black_overlay"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/montant"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="18000.00 DA"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/title_from_to_dots"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/nom_client" />


            <com.haozhang.lib.SlantedTextView
                android:id="@+id/blocage"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/nom_client"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Validé"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="@color/vert"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                app:slantedBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                app:slantedLength="40dp"
                app:slantedMode="right_bottom"
                app:slantedText="IOS"
                app:slantedTextColor="@color/white"
                app:slantedTextSize="16sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image: this the capture image of my item]

Comment: I know using Xamarin I would do some sort of ressource converter with a boolean view model binding.

Comment: In android you can do something similar with bindings using mvvm, bind to a res of your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

If you ignore the arrow/tick in the middle, that is a rectangle shape drawable. The arrow/tick can be a different drawable altogether (vector or image, depending on what you want). Then you try to combine the two in your xml. Rectangle shape sitting on the left and image/vector sitting on top of it in the middle.